# Handling CSV file with CRLF record terminators and unquoted multiline fields with LF terminators for Informatica Developer

Tags: regex, csv, informatica, eol

I have a file I'm feeding to Informatica Developer. I know the file is badly formated, but I **cannot** change it.

This file is a standard CSV file, using semicolons as delimiters. The fields are not between quotes. It uses CRLF end of line characters.

The problem comes from the fact that a few fields contain LF characters.

When I use LF as the row delimiter, the fields containing LF characters break and are not imported right.

I've tried using CR as the row delimiter, but it means that the first field of every row (except the first one) contains "\n". Currently I'm deleting the first character of the first field to get rid of the "\n", but it means that the first character of the first field of the first row is deleted even though it's a legitimate character. I haven't been able to find the right regex to separate that row from the others.

Is there a solution I'm not seeing?

Comment: What tools do or can you use to process the CSV file?

Comment: not sure what system you are using, but if you're on *nix you could pipe your lines into sth like `perl -pne 's/ˆ[\x0a]//'` in order to get rid of the leading "\n"(in case that you've split the lines with CR)

Comment: @lab9, I stated OP wanted to keep those LFs, otherwise the answer as you showed way easier.

Comment: @Emmanuelle, I took the initiative to change the title of your question, in order to better sum up the issue. If it doesn't suit you, feel free to reedit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your explanations:

- Lines terminates by a **CRLF** sequence
- Fields can be multiline with **LF** lines terminators
- It sounds like those **LF** are part of these fields, and therefore **must be kept**

If you have **PERL**, you can process the lines by :

1. setting **CRLFs** as **line terminators** also called **record separators**
2. surrounding the values by double quotes **`"`**

The line performs this task.

```
perl -lpe  'BEGIN {$/ = "\r\n"} s/([^;]+)/"\1"/g' < records.csv
```

Some explanations:

- **`-l`**: "chomps" (remove) the record separator before processing a record line
- **`-p`**: iterates over processed lines and printing the result (see man perlrun)
- **`-e`**: executes a given **script** to process each read lines
- about the **script**:

  - `BEGIN {$/ = "\r\n"}` is a special bloc executed at the beginning, so before the iteration; it tells the end of line is **CRLF** (`\r\n`)
  - `s/([^;]+)/"\1"/g` tells to surround each field (a sequence without semicolons) by double quotes ; this script is iterated by `-p`

Then your CSV datas are protected, and ready to be feed.

Example:

- input (special characters represented):

  ```
   barf;berf\nbirf;borf\r\n
   parf;perf\npirf;porf\r\n
  ```
- result:

  ```
   "barf";"berf
   birf";"borf"
   "parf";"perf
   pirf";"porf"
  ```